# do loop statement is causing an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I am writing a library program that displays a menu of options letting the user add new books to the library, but in my add statement it accepts the title and then gets caught in an infinite loop. I wrote a book class that mainly uses pointers to assign things, if I need to post that I will. But when you run the program it compiles, displays the menu, and when you choose add a book it accepts the title but as soon as you hit enter it starts an a infinite loop.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int bookCounter = 0;
Book library[25];
int menuOption = 0;
char tempt[50] = "\0";
char tempauth[50] = "\0";
char search[50] = "\0";
unsigned int tempp = 0;
do 
    {
        menuOption = 0;

        cout << endl << "1. Show the Library" << endl;
        cout << "2. Add a Book" << endl;
        cout << "3. Search the Library by Title" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit Library" << endl;
        cout << "Select a menu option (e.g. 1, 2, etc.): ";
        cin >> menuOption;

        if(menuOption == 1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < bookCounter; i++)
            {
                library[i].displayBook();
            }
        }
        else if(menuOption == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter the Title: ";
            cin >> tempt[50];
            cout << endl << "Enter the Author's name: " ;
            cin >> tempauth[50];
            cout << endl << "How many pages does the book have? (just enter a         number, e.g. 675, 300): ";
            cin >> tempp;

            library[bookCounter].setAuthor(tempauth);
            library[bookCounter].setTitle(tempt);
            library[bookCounter].setPages(tempp);

            bookCounter++;
            menuOption = 0;
        }
        else if(menuOption == 3)
        {
            cout << "Enter a title you would like search for (will return partial matches): ";
            cin >> search[50];

            for (int i = 0; i < bookCounter; i++)
            {
                int temp = strcmp(search, library[i].getTitle());
                if (temp == 1)
                {
                    library[i].displayBook();
                }
            }
        }

    }while(menuOption != 4);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `cin >> search[50];` will cause out-of-bounds access and expects single character.

Comment: Ask your prof. why he/she has not taught you how to use a debugger before asking for stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the way you are trying to read into the arrays:

```
cin >> tempt[50];
```

This tries to read a single character into the character at index 50 of the array `tempt`, which is outside the bounds of the array (which has valid indices in the range [0,49]).

This means only the first character of the entered title will be consumed from the output. Similarly for author. Hence, only the first two characters which you have entered are actually read. Then, this line will be encountered:

```
cin >> menuOption;
```

Here, what is left in the buffer (the remainder of the title) will be read, expecting a number. As this does not match a valid format for a number, you will get an error flag in `cin`. This will mean that all resulting inputs will also fail, `menuOption` will never change and your program gets stuck in a loop.

A solution to your problem would be to read into `tempt` without index. You can also check if a read has failed using `if(cin.fail())` which should only trigger if there's been an error. If so, handle it and then call `cin.clear()` to reset the error flags.

Answer (score 0):

This

`cin >> tempt[50];`

accesses a non-existent entry in the array. You probably meant to code

`cin >> tempt;`

Or, better, use `std::string` instead of raw char array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line cause the problem,

```
cin >> search[50];
```

You're accessing out bound of `search` array.

Answer (score 0):

One error is when you type in the menu option, the 'return' stays in the input buffer. The next read of `char[]` in your `tempt` variable, will be skipped.

Type `cin.ignore();` after `cin >> menuOption;`

Also, you should read `tempt` instead instead of `tempt[50]`.